# Dark / Light Mode All Page

Tags: javascript, css

In the project I have done, I have implemented the dark light mode structure within the page. I want this to happen on all pages in the project. I want it not to lose its dark light mode feature when the page changes.

```
function toggleDarkLight() {
    var body = document.getElementById("body");
    var currentClass = body.className;
    body.className = currentClass == "light-mode" ? "dark-mode" : "light-mode";
}
```

I'm updating my question. I thought I didn't fully explain. Dark-light mode works flawlessly in the project. For example, what I want to ask is when I switch from page a to page b, it switches back to light mode. However, when I choose dark mode, it should remain dark mode no matter what page I go to.

Comment: You should save the theme info in the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage?retiredLocale=it) and set the proper one at every page load

Comment: Did you consider using the css "prefers-color-scheme" media query?

Comment: _"want it not to lose its dark light mode feature when the page changes"_ - That's nice to know, but what is the actual problem/question?

Comment: The css "prefers-color-scheme" media query doesn't let you toggle inside the app though

Comment: Yes, localStorage seems to be an appropriate solution. @GÖKTUĞ KARABULUT Do you need more guidance on how to implement this?

Comment: Thank you. I found a suitable example. I will review it and apply it to my own project. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

try to use :! `document.body` to get the body,
and `document.body.classList.add("light-mode");` to add a class to the body